# Correct output when there are upto 9 digits but wrong when there are 10 digits of mob number variable

Tags: c

Output shows correct when the phone number variable is upto 9 digits only but shows some random value for 10 digits. Why is this happening?
Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct hotel
{
    char c_name[20];
    int no_days;
    struct phone_number
    {
        int mob;
        int alt_mob;
    }ph;
    
}h;
void read(h*);
void display(h s);
int main()
{
    h h1;
    read(&h1);
    display(h1);
}

void read(h* s)
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&(s->c_name));
    printf("Enter the number of days: ");
    scanf("%d",&(s->no_days));
    printf("Enter the phone number: ");
    scanf("%d",&((s->ph).mob));
    printf("Enter the alternate number: ");
    scanf("%d",&((s->ph).alt_mob));
}
void display(h s)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %d",s.c_name,s.no_days,s.ph.mob,s.ph.alt_mob);
}
```

Comment: did you try searching "is there any limit for the int data type"?

Answer (score 1):

On most systems, an `int` is 32 bit, which means it has a maximum value of 2147483647.  So any value larger than this will overflow.

Phone numbers aren't really "numbers", so they shouldn't be stored in a numerical data type.  You're better off storing it as a string.

Comment: This is the output when mob and alt_mob variable is converted to char[10];

Comment: Enter your name: Abc
Enter the number of days: 20
Enter the phone number: 9999999999
Enter the alternate number: 8888888888
Abc 20 99999999998888888888╠ a 8888888888╠ a

Comment: @SuteerthKalkeri A `char` array of length 10 is not big enough to hold a 10 character string because there's no room for the terminating null bytes.  It needs to have a size of at least 11 for a 10 character string.